# How to use the seletedItem from the AutoCompleteTextView dropdown list?

Tags: android

Friends, I am using AutoCompleteTextView. The Suggestion :

```
String[] recipes={ "Fish", "Chicken", "Mutton"};
```

How do I do this:

When I select one of the item from the dropdown list, it will go to another event?

For example, I type *Fi*, it will come out *Fish* from the dropdown list and then I select Fish, it will go to **another Activity**.

```
package net.learn2develop.Activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoCompleteTextActivity extends Activity {

String[] recipes ={
        "Nasi Lemak With Ikan Bilis",
        "Steamed Cod Fish"
};
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,              android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, recipes);


    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)    findViewById(R.id.txtRecipes);

    textView.setThreshold(3);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int index, long id){

             Intent i=new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
             i.putExtra("item",recipes[index]);
             StartActivity(i);
        }

    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class that implements TextWatcher and override following methods:

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
            // check if entered text is "fish" and if yes then start the new activity.
        }


        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence string,
                final int start, final int count, final int after) {
        }


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence string, final int start,
                final int before, final int count) {
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

receipesBelow Snippet will help you.

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View view,
                        int index, long id)
                {
                    //index will give you item which you selected
                                    Now start another activity here
                                    Intent i=new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
                                    i.putExtra("item",recipes[index]);
                                    StartActivity(i);


                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            })
```

**SecondActivity.java**

You can retrieve that value is onCreate like below

```
String selectedItem=getIntent().getStringExtra("item");
```

Comment: i have error on the setOnItemSelectedListener.. Do I have import somthing?

Comment: what error you have!if you point out your cursor over red line you will get to see error.

Comment: The error show: The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AutoCompleteTextView is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener{})

Answer (score 0):

You should have used `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnItemSelectedListener`.